How to organize a very illogical Plotly sankey diagram
My diagram is complex, with 189 nodes.  But I expected the layout to be more logical, based on the flow of data from source to target.  It is completely circuitous and loopy.
These are trades flowing through an algo trading system, so there are entries, targets, and stops.  I expected there to be a natural layout with entries on the left, targets in the middle, and final exits on the right.  To a certain extent, the entries and stops happened that way, but the middle is a mess.  The actual data flows more logically than the way this diagram depicts.
For example, there are flows from ratchet bracket 1 to ratchet bracket 2 to ratchet bracket 3, so I assumed that these would appear in order from left to right, but they do not.  The same with grab cents 1, 2, and 3.
Is there any way to coax Plotly into rendering this in a more logical, flow-based way?  Or can I somehow influence the placement by ordering the lists that feed the diagram?  Is there another Sankey implementation that might handle this better?  I am doing this in Google Colab. 
I've also found that dragging things into order does not make the render look any better.  Instead of flowing direction from ratchet bracket 3 to 4, the connection continues to go the wrong direction, joined with a disjointed off-screen connection.  It is impossible to follow.

Update following answer
I followed the advice in Serge's answer, which helped, but did not solve all the problems.  Why, for example, are there so many nodes at the edges, why are there still "retrograde" paths when nodes are introduced in their order of appearance, and why aren't the major nodes spaced more evenly?
Is there anything else I can do to make this diagram come out more user-friendly?  The white space is obviously not well-utilized.  I tried experimenting with the dimensions, but it didn't seem to help in that regard.


You need to order the nodes in a meaningful manner. For example, place entry nodes first, then intermediate nodes, and finally exit nodes. Layer the nodes and if possible adjust the links. Here is an example.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'source': ['entry1', 'entry2', 'entry3', 'entry4', 'entry5',
               'ratchet_bracket1', 'ratchet_bracket1', 'ratchet_bracket2', 'ratchet_bracket3', 'ratchet_bracket4',
               'grab_cents1', 'grab_cents2', 'grab_cents3', 'grab_cents4', 'grab_cents5',
               'target1', 'target2', 'target3', 'target4', 'target5'],
    'target': ['ratchet_bracket1', 'ratchet_bracket2', 'ratchet_bracket3', 'grab_cents1', 'grab_cents2',
               'ratchet_bracket2', 'target1', 'ratchet_bracket3', 'target2', 'target3',
               'grab_cents2', 'grab_cents3', 'target4', 'target5', 'ratchet_bracket4',
               'final_exit1', 'final_exit2', 'final_exit3', 'final_exit4', 'final_exit5'],
    'value': [10, 15, 10, 12, 14, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 10, 15, 11, 13, 12, 20, 18, 22, 24, 19]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

import plotly.graph_objects as go

all_nodes = list(pd.unique(df[['source', 'target']].values.ravel('K')))
mapping = {node: idx for idx, node in enumerate(all_nodes)}

df['source_idx'] = df['source'].map(mapping)
df['target_idx'] = df['target'].map(mapping)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node=dict(
        pad=15,
        thickness=20,
        line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
        label=all_nodes,
    ),
    link=dict(
        source=df['source_idx'],  
        target=df['target_idx'],
        value=df['value']
    )
)])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Sankey Diagram of Algo Trading System", font_size=10)
fig.show()


which gives


Thank you for your answer!  Can you please explain what you meant by "Layer the nodes and if possible adjust the links."?  It seems like the main thing you did was to put the source array into the same order that events happen in the Trade Plans.  Is that the key to getting a logical diagram?  Is that what you meant by "layering the nodes," or is that something else?  How do you "adjust the links"?

Layering nodes means arranging them in a way that visually represents the stages or phases of a process. For example, in a trading system: Entry nodes are at the beginning (e.g., sources of transactions or initial decisions), Intermediate nodes follow (e.g., processing steps, decision points) and exit nodes are at the end (e.g., final outcomes or destinations). Adjusting the links means ensuring that connections between nodes are clear and do not  overlap or create visual confusion.
Ordering the nodes within each layer to minimize crossings. Adjusting the of links to avoids overlaps.

That makes sense, but in your code, I do not see you doing either of those things.  You have a single list of nodes with no distinction between entry, intermediate, and exit, aside from the order in which they appear.  Is that all there is to "layering," or are there other tools you can use?  And you are not doing anything in particular to the links, are you?  I don't mean to be ungrateful.  I'm just trying to understand how to incorporate your suggestions into my very complex diagram.  I will try ordering the source nodes, but I'm not sure what to do differently with the links.
